# How to blur a closed path element in Paper.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, paperjs, gaussianblur

Is it possible to blur a closed path element that has a fill using paperjs? Would I have to create an SVG feGaussianBlur primitive for each path that I wanted to blur? How would that affect performance if there were a few hundred path elements on the canvas? I thought about making use of the shadowBlur with some color magic, where the shadow would match the selected path, but it's not quite the same effect. I do not want to use raster.

Comment: Thank you for responding, however, that does not answer the questions. However, based on your answer, I can assume that applying the feGaussianBlur is the only way and that I would ultimately need to create multiple blur elements for every path that I wanted blurred. Particularly if I didn't want all the paths to use the same blur.

Comment: You can use currentColor or CSS variables to have a single filter that matches the colour of the object it's filtering.

Answer (score 1):

A trick could be to use the `shadowBlur` property of the item.
The only thing is that the shadow is only drawn if the item has a fill.
And we don't want the fill to be displayed but only the shadow.
So we could make clever usage of blend modes to hide the fill but not the shadow.
Here's a simple [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/XZBBa8MwDIX/ivAlG5R2DHbxbuu5MNhx2UGxNWyi2MGWF0Lpf5/TNNuYDzKSeN976KwCDqS0eutJjFM7ZaJd+kATvKK4/dEnw3R3blMboD5DQShp+PI07ddmt+0SWl+yhqeHn1F2aON0jByrpukYTd/8W75wqbvHVdNKJiYjZLWkQrfZ4QCZBBA+PTOYhQYSYcCeIJdEIA6lFrohwWewPo+MM9nNbdFuQSbnhX6DVH7JBB1TsEM9wAJ3fvkr8uqJwUIMPNcc9MdojXfVnapON0Nh8SPPK/ty/1xP2iXCfow+SFb6/ePyDQ==) demonstrating this.

```js
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowBlur: 20,
    selected: true,
    // set a fill color to make sure that the shadow is displayed
    fillColor: 'white',
    // use blendmode to hide the fill and only see the shadow
    blendMode: 'multiply',
});
```

---

### edit

This technique indeed seems to reach a limit when trying to stack items on top of each other.
We can prevent the `multiply` blend mode from "bleeding out" by wrapping the item into a group which has a blend mode of `source-over`. This has the effect to scope the children blend modes.
But there is still a trick to find to compose the items together.
Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating where I stopped my investigation.
I'm quite sure that you can find a solution following this track.

```js
function drawBlurryCircle(center, radius, blurAmount, color) {
    const circle = new Path.Circle({
        center,
        radius,
        shadowColor: color,
        shadowBlur: blurAmount,
        // set a fill color to make sure that the shadow is displayed
        fillColor: 'white',
        // use blendmode to hide the fill and only see the shadow
        blendMode: 'multiply'
    });

    const blurPlaceholder = circle
        .clone()
        .set({ shadowColor: null, fillColor: null })
        .scale((circle.bounds.width + (blurAmount * 2)) / circle.bounds.width);

    return new Group({
        children: [circle, blurPlaceholder],
        blendMode: 'source-over'
    });
}

drawBlurryCircle(view.center, 50, 20, 'red');
drawBlurryCircle(view.center + 30, 40, 30, 'lime');
drawBlurryCircle(view.center + 60, 30, 30, 'blue');
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thought about doing something like this but couldn't figure out how to get the transparent fill. Thanks!

Comment: So multiply is cool, but how would you pull this off with multiple objects stacked on top of one another while not multiplying those objects? For example, if I put down a red blurry object, then a lighter red one on top of that, the lighter one disappears or is barely visible. Maybe some trick where a second, opaque, path is added above the blurred parent and scaled to end where the blur begins? Changing the blur amount would change that child element scale I guess?

Comment: How would I target a path element to add feGaussianBlur?

Comment: See my edit for a more advanced solution.